# multi level group headers in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

```
            Main-header

   subhead1 |subhead2 |subhead3

subhead1 |subhead2 |subhead |subhead4


----------------------------------------
        column names come here
----------------------------------------
```

Can we have the multilevel headers in JQGrids as shown above.Can any one please.

Comment: If you are still looking for a resolution, there is a new answer on the following question. I think it is the best solution yet. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24016304/2807912

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean under subheadres because you placed all column names in the last line and included 3 levels or come kind of headers.

What you can do is use `caption` option of jqGrid to create "Main-header". You can additionally create **one** level of column grouping with respect of [setGroupHeaders](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar) method like described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar). More levels of subheads are not supported.

**UPDATED**: A possible implementation of multilevel grouping of headers I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18991671/315935).